# How to auto-expand parent based on child's content

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `div`, inside which I need to float two child `div` elements. The first one has fixed width, second one will be a carousel of sorts, containing an unpredictable number of elements. What I want - is that the carousel should expand automatically as more and more child elements appear, and proportionately, the parent should expand as well, but only upto a certain extent (90% of the body width). Beyond that, the parent element should remain at fixed width, and the second child element at fixed width as well, and the elements inside that second child being horizontally scrollable.

My HTML is something like this:

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 90%;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child1,
.child2 {
  float: left;
}

.child2 {
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
  width: calc(100%-30px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: pink;
}

.clear {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'>
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class='child2'>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

When this executed, it works fine, but because the number of child elements in the child container is low enough for my monitor size. When I add more child elements (`.child3`) to push the parent beyond 90% of the available body width, I find that a vertical scrollbar appears instead of horizontal, while pushing the child element down.

How do I make it horizontally scrollable, while keeping it at the same fixed width (`calc(100%-30px)`), and both child elements floating side by side? This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8smx6nut/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `white-space` property, but only if you dispense with the `float`s. Make everything `inline-block`s instead.

Also you had an error in the `calc` function: the `-` sign should be followed by a space, otherwise it is parsed as the two values 100% and -30px without an operator in between.

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child1,
.child2 {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.child2 {
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: pink;
}

.clear {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'>
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class='child2'>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
    <div class='child3'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks promising. There is, however, an annoying little vertical scroll bar appearing, which lets me scroll it slightly.

Comment: That is because the height of .child2 includes the height of the horizontal scrollbar. Ergo, if there is a scrollbar, the effective height drops to something like 40px rather than 60. There is no CSS solution, since CSS can't detect if the scrollbar is present or not. Use JavaScript for that. With CSS only, all you can do is make the height of .child2 bigger.

Comment: There is a proposal for a property named [`scrollbar-gutter`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-4/#scollbar-gutter-property) which will solve that problem, but that is not a solution right now, sorry.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Increasing the height does solve the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think found how to make the horizontal scroll bar you want. On `.Child2` these styles seemed to make the biggest difference. `max-width: 90%;` `overflow: auto;` `overflow-x: scroll;` `white-space: nowrap;`

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <p>Foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
        <div class="child3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 90%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: #ebe573;
    border: 1px solid #fffa0c;
    height: 100px;

}
.child1, .child2 {
    float: left;
}
.child2 {
    height: 80px;
    background: green;
    width: calc(100%-30px);
    margin: 8px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.child3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #00ff15;
}
```